# Django - For loop gives results for only one item

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, for-loop, django-views

I have the following `ListView`:

```
class SongList(generic.ListView):
    model = models.Song
    template_name = 'videos/song_list.html'
    context_object_name = 'song_list'
```

Where I am overwriting `get_context_data`:

```
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(generic.ListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
```

And now I want to perform some operations on every song in order to display it on my template, so I do:

```
        for song in context['song_list']:
            song = models.Song.objects.get(title=song)
            lyrics_list = models.Song.objects.get(title=song).lyrics_as_list()
            
            import pymorphy2
            morph = pymorphy2.MorphAnalyzer()

            lyrics_list_lemma = []
            for word in set(lyrics_list):
                parsed_word = morph.parse(word)[0]
                result = {
                    'word_original': word,
                    'word_normalized': parsed_word.normal_form,
                        }
                lyrics_list_lemma.append(result)
            context['lyrics_lemma'] = lyrics_list_lemma
            context['count'] = len([k for d in lyrics_list_lemma for k in d.keys() if k == 'word_normalized'])
        return context
```

I get the correct values for `lyrics_list_lemma` and `count`, *but only for one song*. Shouldn't I be getting it for all the songs, since it falls under the `for` loop?

Comment: Have you tried debugging and checking the value of context['song_list']? It's probably getting overridden by something.

Comment: Yes, I know `context[song_list]` gives the correct values because it works in other functions I have in the same view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are over-riding the value with each loop. Declare the list outside the loop.

**Ex:**

```
context['lyrics_lemma'] = []
context['count'] = []
for song in context['song_list']:
    song = models.Song.objects.get(title=song)
    lyrics_list = models.Song.objects.get(title=song).lyrics_as_list()
    
    import pymorphy2
    morph = pymorphy2.MorphAnalyzer()

    lyrics_list_lemma = []
    for word in set(lyrics_list):
        parsed_word = morph.parse(word)[0]
        result = {
            'word_original': word,
            'word_normalized': parsed_word.normal_form,
                }
        lyrics_list_lemma.append(result)
    context['lyrics_lemma'].append(lyrics_list_lemma)
    context['count'].append(len([k for d in lyrics_list_lemma for k in d.keys() if k == 'word_normalized']))
return context
```

---

Also you probably need a dictionary or a list of dictionary

```
context['data'] = []
for song in context['song_list']:
    .....
    context['data'].append({"lyrics_lemma": lyrics_list_lemma, 
                            "count": len([k for d in lyrics_list_lemma for k in d.keys() if k == 'word_normalized']))
```

Or

```
context['data'] = {}
for song in context['song_list']:
    .....
    context['data'].update({song: {"lyrics_lemma": lyrics_list_lemma, 
                                   "count": len([k for d in lyrics_list_lemma for k in d.keys() if k == 'word_normalized'])}})
```